# Sitecore 9.3 - adding Identity Provider

Tags: identity-server

I am trying to add a IdentityProvider in Sitecore 9.3 as shown below:

```
<federatedAuthentication>   
  <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
    <identityProvider id="sc9devsujana.azureAD" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
      <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
      <caption>Sign-in with Azure Active Directory</caption>
      <domain>sitecore</domain>
      <icon>/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/msazure.png</icon>
      </identityProvider>
  </identityProviders>
  <!-- Property initializer assigns claim values to sitecore user properties -->
  <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
    <maps hint="list">
      <map name="email claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
        <data hint="raw:AddData">
          <!--claim name-->
          <source name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" />
          <!--property name-->
          <target name="Email" />
        </data>
      </map>
      <map name="Name claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
        <data hint="raw:AddData">
          <!--claim name-->
          <source name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" />
          <!--property name-->
          <target name="Name" />
        </data>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </propertyInitializer>
  <identityProvidersPerSites>
    <mapEntry name="all" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true" >
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>shell</site>
        <site>login</site>
        <site>admin</site>
        <site>service</site>
        <site>modules_shell</site>
        <site>modules_website</site>
        <site>website</site>
        <site>scheduler</site>
        <site>system</site>
        <site>publisher</site>
      </sites>
      <!-- Registered identity providers for above providers -->
      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='sc9devsujana.azureAD']" />
      </identityProviders>
       <!-- ExternalUserBuilder is what creates a user with customusername in Sitecore and assigns roles based on claim transformation configured above -->
      <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true" >
        <param desc="isPersistentUser">true</param>
      </externalUserBuilder>
    </mapEntry>
  </identityProvidersPerSites>
</federatedAuthentication>
```

On loading, it gives an error 
[image]
Any help on how to resolve this much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.IdentityProvider` is an abstract class. You either need to implement your own provider that inherits from that abstract class or use the default implementation provided by Sitecore: `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider`

Relevant section from [the documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/configure-federated-authentication.html#UUID-104ba4a1-c4ab-226a-c98d-4d1764e62f2a_N1525852374443):

> Enter values for the id and type attributes. The type must implement the abstract class Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.IdentityProvider. Sitecore has a default implementation –Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider.

Comment: I tried with defaultIdentityProvider and it returns the following error   Server Error in '/' Application.

Identity provider "" was not found in configuration.

Comment: I tried the configuration you've shared in the question and I did get one error after changing the `IdentityProvider` to `DefaultIdentityProvider` but that seemed to be related to the `resolve="true"` attribute you've added to the provider declaration. Once I removed that I didn't see any errors

Comment: That's interesting, is that Sitecore 9.3? This code works in 9.0.2, but mine gives error in 9.3

Comment: the environment I tested in was 9.2. Maybe something has changed in 9.3?

Comment: That's right, I am looking for that change, not able to figure out the exact problem. Thanks for your time Christian

Comment: Chirstian - If you could let me know where you have applied this patching, it would be of great help. I have this patch in sc9dev website, or should it be at a different place?

Comment: @Sujana: It sounds like your config is in the right place. Please share the `<federatedAuthentication>` section from the `sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` output and I can see if I can spot any issues

Comment: The issue is resolved, it was actually due to Identity Subprovider configuration in the patch file and another config where the name of identity subprovider was hard coded. thank you for all the help.